# Show notification if an edit is pending

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, android-app

On the Android app if you edit a post that has an edit pending approval you can edit the post without any notification of that and submitting your edit will decline the pending edit. Would it be possible for some pop-up referring to the pending edit and you submitting your edit will decline the pending edit?